# Compiler errors with sequoyah, but build well from command line

Tags: android, android-ndk

This is really frustrating
- I can build my native code from command line, but when I build from eclipse(Sequoyah plug-in enabled) its simply through simple compilation errors like headers not found...
EVen when i build the library from command line everytime I try to run from eclipse it rebuuilds and there goes errors again 
- I'm frustrated as I ran out of option to locate the issue
Can some one shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is *Unresolved inclusion* with error markers at each header that Eclipse's editor cannot find.  This is confounding when you see it, because it is expected that after installing Sequoyah and the ADT, pointing the Sequoyah configuration to your NDK, that you'd have everything you need to start coding.

Two things to observe.  The process of building in the ADT "Android Perspective" will work until you click on one of your C/C++ files in your jni directory.  Once you open one of these, you'll see the error marker and the project will be tagged as containing errors.

Second observation, when you convert the project to C/C++ perspective or to Sequoyah's Android Native perspective (apparently there's two ways to skin this cat), you will have the ability to configure the project settings around NDK toolchain, include paths, and builder settings.  This is where you can set the ndk-build to automatically fire off on each change.  And funny thing too is that the ndk-build will work fine until you click on one of your C/C++ sources.

So solution, click [here] http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm and you'll get instructions for configuring the CDT's include paths.  You want to set your include paths for C/C++ (either, or both) so that you get to the platform folder includes.

Example, I've got my project hello-jni-to-the-world project set to android-9.  So configure the include path: android-ndk-r6b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include .  Now the magic won't show up until you click apply/save and you'll be prompted to rebuild the indexes.

There are two to three other threads on Stackoverflow asking the same question, and I'll have to find them and add them to the comments.  Basically, there were no definitive answers and there's a lot of the usual answering a question with a question: which version of NDK do you have, can you post your code, did you install java, is your computer on ?

Comment: @ruedat101 : I solved this however by rebuilding the index, but for my friend get these errors show up even after rebuilding index, However I see your answer logical. I'm using ndk rb7 Yes Java is installed, and I'm working on OSX Lion

Comment: Shrini -- the questions in the last paragraph were actually there as an example of the unhelpful diagnosis that I found in other posts about this very same question.  Glad it worked.  Keep in mind that your friend may see problems if the include paths were added for C++ but not for C.  Depends on whether the native code is C or C++.  Might ask the friend to double check that.